# How to handle membership levels with ASP.NET Roles

Tags: asp.net, authorization, roles

I am building a subscription based web site, which currently has three subscription levels, i.e. Horses, Soccer, and Horses and Soccer.  I was thinking of implementing standard role based authorization, where a Horses subscriber would get roles including those to use the Horses section, etc.

Should I use a standard role provider, and when a member subscribes to the site, assign roles for his subscription to him, or use a hierarchical role provider, that when asked for the roles for a member, only then uses the member's subscription level to 'calculate' a set of roles for the member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be aspnet roles and assing the roles seems like a good solution to me that requires minimal amount of code

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 is more controlled and deterministic as opposed to approach 2.

It will depend on how many 'public' areas you have.. If there are manu public areas and roles apply only to chosen few content, I would go with option 2 otherwise option 1.